# Chrome not rendering Google Charts (Stacked Bar Chart) correctly with <base href="/"> tag

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-visualization

I have an Angularjs app that uses `<base href="/">` in the header for pretty URLS. This `base` tag seems to be causing my Google Chart (Stacked Bar Chart) to flow outside my stacked bar.

Here is how it looks like in other browsers.
[image]

In Chrome, it looks like this.

[image]

You can test it out here with this Plunker. Just open this with Chrome.
http://plnkr.co/edit/RFUykT4ldyya93VWLxMr?p=preview

If I remove the `base` tag, Chrome will render it correctly.  What is going on here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Froze version 43 work. (see instructions here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements#frozen-versions )

https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2072

Answer (score 0):

The [similar issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/598) has been reported in [google-visualization-issues](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues) GitHub repository already.

The workaround would be to *to prepend `window.location` before the hash in all the elements containing the `clip-path` attribute*:

```
function fixChart() {
    $('[clip-path]').each(function () {
        var fixedClipPath = $(this).attr('clip-path').replace('#', window.location + '#');
        $(this).attr('clip-path', fixedClipPath);
    });
}
```

**Working example**

```js
google.charts.load('41', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'test');
    // a column for each bar (each bar has 1 data point)
    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'test');
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });

    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'test');
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });

    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'test');
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });

    dataTable.addRows([
      ['test',
        58,
        'color: #59a9c0', // sky blue
        7,
        'color: #4ab87b', // sea green
        5,
        'color: gray'
      ]
    ]);

    // Setting Chart Options
    var options = {
        tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' },
        legend: 'none',
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                min: 35,
                max: 80
            },
            ticks: [35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 58, 60, 65, 70] // display labels every specified point
        }

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_stacked'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', fixChart);
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}

function fixChart() {
    $('[clip-path]').each(function () {
        var fixedClipPath = $(this).attr('clip-path').replace('#', window.location + '#');
        $(this).attr('clip-path', fixedClipPath);
    });
}
```

```html
<base href="/">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chartWithOverlay">
    <div id="barchart_stacked" style="width: 900px; height: 90px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code snippet displays the chart incorrectly in Firefox 41.0.